# Wrong dates for Stack Exchange Network Status posts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackstatus

There seems to be something not quite right about some recent posts to [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net), the "Stack Exchange Network Status" blog.

The most recent post titled [Data Explorer Maintenance - July 21, 2014](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/92575084134/data-explorer-maintenance-july-21-2014) claims a post date of July 23 (today), about 16 hours ago. This makes no sense given that the maintenance date suggested by the title (July 21) is before the current date (July 23).

Another example is a post titled [Chat maintenance: July 22, 2014 at 9 pm EST (1 am UTC)](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/92572393494/chat-maintenance-july-22-2014-at-9-pm-est-1-am-utc). The first sentence states:

> We will be shuffling some databases around between the clusters on Thursday around 9 pm.

The problem is that July 22, the date in the post title, is not a Thursday.

Comment: Someone forgot to flip the calendar pages *again*; it is still stuck on May 2014....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my defense, we didn't think anyone read those.

I have no real reason these dates were wrong, I'm just an idiot apparently - sorry!

Comment: Admit it, you were just checking if someone really read those posts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have no idea what you're talking about.